# Jquery Ajax Events - Determine element that triggered ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to capture the beforeSend event for all `<form>` submits on my site. We also have jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js that I'm trying to not modify or interfere with. I've tried the following approach:

```
$(document).on("ajaxSend", function (e, request, settings) {
    console.log("before send");
}).on("ajaxComplete", function (e) {
    console.log("complete");
}).on("ajaxSuccess ", function (e) {
    console.log("success");
}).on("ajaxError ", function (e) {
    console.log("error");
});
```

However with the above approach, I'm getting all ajax requests, not just `<form>` submits. If I could identify what element triggered the ajax request (if any), that would allow me to continue but the `e.target` is just 'document'. I can't seem to be able to get a reference to the `<form>` element (if any).

Another approach I've tried is hooking into all submit events:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) { ... });
```

But I'm not seeing a way to hook into the beforeSend event and still allow it process through jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js (which uses the above event handler and manually calls `$.ajax`)

Comment: Nothing automatically connects the AJAX call with the original event whose listener called it.

Answer (score 0):

All the handler functions receive the `ajaxOptions` object that was passed to `$.ajax()`. So you can add a property to that to hold a reference to the original event.

```
$("selector").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "...",
        element: this,
        ...
    });
);

$(document).on({
    ajaxSend: function(e, request, settings) {
        if (settings.element) {
            // code 
        }
    },
    ajaxComplete: function(e, request, settings) {
        if (settings.element) {
            // code
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

This will only work for AJAX requests that you send from *your* code, since you can add the `element:` property. It won't work for AJAX requests triggered by third-party libraries.